# Scheduled events on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, notifications, scheduling

I'm currently creating a web app using ASP.net that tracks a number of tasks that all have a due date stored in a SQL database.

My goal is to have the server notify the user when the due date has passed, whether it's via email, on the browser interface, or via other means of communication.

There will potentially be thousands of tasks that can be due at any time, so I think that polling is inefficient.

What is the "correct" or "best" way to achieve this using C#? A general explanation of the process would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know alot about the technology but I think Signalr is probably what you want.

see [signalr.net](http://signalr.net)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best ways is using asynchronous programming with `async` and `await` that explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to run a scheduler which retrieves data from database and process them in an interval.

For example, every hour retrieves users whose due date has passed, and send notifications to those users.

There are multiple ways of scheduling task. Here is one easy method -

[Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)